# Facebook Login for same app on UWP AND WP8.1 - Which SID?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, facebook-login

On the Settings page of my Facebook App, I can only add one Windows App. However, my app exists both as a UWP app AND a Windows Phone 8.1 app.
Hence I have two pairs of Windows Store Id + Windows Phone Store Id.

How can I set that up without creating two Facebook apps?

Comment: (Considering you have created only one app for both 8.1 and UWP) I added SID which we get in App management->App identity->URL for Windows Phone 8.1 and earlier(remove '-'  from the url)  in  Windows Phone Store SID [BETA] field . It works fine in both platforms

Comment: I use Xamarin and I created two projects: one for UWP and one for WP8.1. It then generates two apps. They are not published to the store yet as I want Facebook to work first. Are you saying I should use the same pairs of SID for UWP and 8.1 and publish them both on the same Store app? (I've never published to windows store before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you create two application packages to submit to the store doesn't mean they have to be separate entries in the store.
By uploading both packages to the same store entry you'll be able to use the same IDs in both.

Comment: Actually they get the same Windows Store Id but none has a Windows Phone SID. Even I force them to have the same id in the manifest I can't get the WinPhone version to log in Facebook.